# How to get non overlapping time windows of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, series, rolling-computation

I have a Pandas dataframe with a series of events, each with a time stamp. I'd like to get all windows that cover all points, with a given fixed time (say 1 second). For example, something like this would work iteratively:

```
start_of_windows = []

new_time = None
for event_time in df.timestamps:
  if new_time and event_time < new_time: continue
  
  # start of a new window
  start_of_windows.append(event_time)

  new_time = event_time + 1s
```

I tried getting this with `.rolling(window='1s', min_periods=1)` but this doesn't work as the windows overlap each other.

`resample` doesn't work either as there might be a long gap between events, and I only want a window when necessary.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you share some brief example data and expected output?  [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)